# Calling Oracle store procedure with output parameter from SQL server through linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

i have created a linked server from sql server to oracle 11g database, i want to run a store procedure with output parameter from  oracle 11g database to sql server but i keep getting errors.....

Can i get help from here..

Comment: Please edit your post to show us _formatted_ code, and tell us what the actual error is.  No one can debug code they cannot see, looking for an unknown error.

Comment: i want to know how to write the query that will allow me to call the procedure with an output parameter from oracle 11g to SQL Server using Linked Server.....